# Adjusting weighting and df for constant variance

Tags: regression, diagnostic

Faraways Linear models (2ed), page 75, does the following:

```
data(savings,package="faraway")
lmod <- lm(sr ~ pop15+pop75+dpi+ddpi,savings)
sumary(lm(sqrt(abs(residuals(lmod))) ~ fitted(lmod)))

              Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   2.162163   0.347880  6.2153 1.175e-07
fitted(lmod) -0.061366   0.034756 -1.7656   0.08382

n = 50, p = 2, Residual SE = 0.63415, R-Squared = 0.06
```

He says:-"This test is not quite right, as some weighting should be used and the degrees of freedom should be adjusted". What does he mean by this exactly, and how would I go about adding weights and adjusting the degrees of freedom in R?

Comment: For Faraway's weighted least squares treatment, go to page 116.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Thank you for the suggestion, I have had a quick skim and its definitely what I need but I will get there gradually. Additionally, he mentions "if a problem is solely one of non-constant variance with no suggestion of non-linearity then the use of weighted least squares may be appropriate". Are weighted least squares appropriate only for this situation or are other methods also useful?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that, but you can still use linear regression in the face of non-linearity via transformations. The "linear" in "linear regression" has to do with the coefficients you're trying to find showing up linearly in your model, and nothing at all to do with whether the shape you're trying to fit is a straight line.